# preselected list menu or checkboxes from mySQL results in php

Tags: php

I'm no great shakes when it comes to php.  mastered quiet a bit but this one is pushing my lack of knowledge a bit today.

I have a multiple select list, populated from some SQL results...  so far so good

```
<select name="groups[]" size="1" multiple class="groups" id="select">
<?php
do {  
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_rsGroups['group']?>">
    <?php echo $row_rsGroups['group']?>
    </option>
    <?php
} while ($row_rsGroups = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsGroups));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($rsGroups);
if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($rsGroups, 0);
    $row_rsGroups = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsGroups);
}
?>
</select>
```

that works fine and dandy, but where I want to go next, is to have certain values on the list already highlighted, the ones to be highlighted coming from an array.

so the list arrives on the page with all the available groups in it, ie, legal, sales, marketing, admin, promotions etc

but I would like one or more of these to be already highlighted dependant on the array, ie, legal and sales, so $group_array = "legal,sales"

which is where I have become a bit stuck

hope that make sense

had thought about providing this as a bunch of checkboxes instead but got even more stuck and couldn't quite get my head around getting the checkboxes to generate

help!!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in this format as a string: `local,sales` this would work:

```
<select name="groups[]" size="1" multiple class="groups" id="select">
    <?php
    do {  
        $selected = "";
        if (substr_count($group_array, $row_rsGroups['group']) > 0) $selected = " selected=\"selected\";
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_rsGroups['group']?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>>
        <?php echo $row_rsGroups['group']?>
        </option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_rsGroups = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsGroups));
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsGroups);
    if($rows > 0) {
        mysql_data_seek($rsGroups, 0);
        $row_rsGroups = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsGroups);
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Now, if you data is in an array, ie `_POST` or `_GET` you should change the `if` to:

`if (in_array($row_rsGroups['group'], $group_array))`